# How to Vertical ion-item Scroll to Bottom and Top on Down and Up arrow icon button click in ionic 4?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 plus Angular App, I want to add Up And Down Arrow 
Button to Scroll Vertically Top To Bottom And Vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the ionic docs for info on component methods https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

.html

```
 <ion-content>
   <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" (click)="scrollToBottom()"></ion-icon>

    //..... your content ......

     <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup" (click)="scrollToTop()"></ion-icon>
 </ion-content>
```

.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import {IonContent} from '@ionic/angular';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {
         @ViewChild(IonContent) theContent: IonContent;


    scrollToBottom(){
    this.theContent.scrollToBottom();
}
   scrollToTop(){
    this.theContent.scrollToTop();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Content component to handle scrolling in code.
You can use `scrollToTop()` or `scrollToBottom()` as well as `scrollToPoint()`, whatever fits your need.

For more info see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#scrollToTop

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```